# Debugging Shell Script Pycharm

Tags: python, bash, debugging, pycharm

I have a shell script that I wish to debug i.e I want to turn on debugging option in Pycharm for this shell script. I have added the bash plugin to Pycharm and I Edited configurations for the bash file as follows:
[image]

I added the path to the script as well as the path to the python interpreter. However, Debug is still greyed out:

[image]

How can I turn on the debug option ? Or it does not work at all for shell scripts ?

Comment: Shell plugin doesn't support debugging.

Comment: @PavelKarateev so does that mean I cannot debug shell scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

check if your program(code) is running in the background or not if it is running you cannot debug it. First you will have to stop the running code and then hit the debuging button.

Comment: its not running in the background at all. The debug option is working for all ```.py``` files I have except for this ```.sh``` file

Comment: @Perl check this (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-shell-script.html)